# How do I kill react-native app using Expo Cli pragmatically for iOS?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I want to kill the application pragmatically. I am using expo cli in my application. I found one solution https://github.com/wumke/react-native-exit-app, but it doesn't seems compatible with expo cli. I don't want to eject expo. Is there another way I can pragmatically kill iOS app without ejecting expo?

Answer (score -1):

If you don't use the module, you can't solve the problem at this time in `Expo`.

Similar to the module, there is a module called `BackHandler`, but **iOS** does not.

- **Android**: Detect hardware back button presses, and programmatically
  invoke the default back button functionality to exit the app if there
  are no listeners or if none of the listeners return true.
- **tvOS**: Detect presses of the menu button on the TV remote. (Still to
  be implemented: programmatically disable menu button handling
  functionality to exit the app if there are no listeners or if none of
  the listeners return true.)
- **iOS**: Not applicable.